# Access monogo db via python

Tags: python, mongodb

I am new to **mongodb** and I am trying to connect it **remotely** (from my local system to live db) and it is connected successfully. I can restrict the access to some ip's from server but I need one **password restriction** as well means If any user try to connect to db , he must define password or both username/password.
rt now my code for connecting to mongo db is :

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, Connection

c = MongoClient('myip',27017)

a = c.mydb.testData.find()
```

Now it gets the database mydb data but here I haven't provide any password . Now I want that it must ask for password. So please tell me where i can define this password so that very I can send this password in mongoclient.

Comment: Take a look at [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/#create-the-system-user-administrator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [authenticate](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.authenticate)

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo import database as DB

conn = MongoClient("127.0.0.1", "27017")     # host, port
db = DB.Database(conn, "my_db_name")         # db name
db.authenticate("username", "password")      # username, password
```

Comment: this username/password cab be any user which i have added in the mongodb , right ? and if he doesn't have permission then he will not be connected to the db

Comment: You have to use `admin` account to create user and roles(permission) on mongodb first.